# Operator "+": is it really overloaded for strings?

Tags: java, string, operator-overloading

I often hear people say that the plus (`+`) operator for `String` objects is **an overloaded operator**. Why? Which operators does it overload?

*I know what this operator does and how it works. I also know that Java doesn't support user-defined overloaded operators.*

Comment: It merely **resembles** an overloaded operator such as one would find in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not overloaded. It's a *concatenation* operator for strings defined at the language level. See [String Concatenation Operator +](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1).